# How to reduce time problem while cracking short password with Python crypt module?

Tags: python, crypt

i am trying to crack short paswords. Passwords length should be either 1-3(alphanumerical) or 1-6 only numerical.
I have passwords.txt and dictionary.txt files. If dictionary can't help us to find password then i have to find with brute force

My problem is, i can only solve if the length of password is 6(numerical) or 3(alphanumerical) as you can see.

```
import crypt
import secrets
import string


def testPass(cryptPass):

salt = cryptPass[0:2]
dictFile = open('dictionary.txt', 'r')

for word in dictFile.readlines():

    word = word.strip('\n')
    cryptWord = crypt.crypt(word, salt)

    if(cryptWord == cryptPass):
        print('Found password:', word, '\n')
        return

alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
alphabet2 = string.digits


while(True):


    numericPassword = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet2) for i in range(6))
    cryptedWord = crypt.crypt(numericPassword, salt)


    alphaNumericPassword = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(3))
    cryptedWord2 = crypt.crypt(alphaNumericPassword, salt)


    if(cryptPass == cryptedWord):
        print('Password found:', numericPassword, '\n')
        break


    elif(cryptPass == cryptedWord2):
        print('Password found:', alphaNumericPassword, '\n')
        break



def main():


print()

passFile = open('passwords.txt')

for line in passFile.readlines():

    if ":" in line:

        user = line.split(':')[0]
        cryptPass = line.split(':')[1].strip('\n')
        print("Cracking password for:", user)
        testPass(cryptPass)


main()
```

I tried to add more lines like

```
alphaNumericPassword = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(1))
alphaNumericPassword = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(2))
```

or

```
  numericPassword = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet2) for i in range(4))

  numericPassword = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet2) for i in range(5))
```

but when i add these lines it doesn't produce any outcomes(I suppose because of there are too much possibilites). I tried nested loops either but nothing changed. How can i figure it out?

Comment: The formatting of the example code is broken so I may be wrong but it looks like your checking versus a randomly generated passwords instead of having some logic to check all possibilities one by one in you "brute force" part.
If you try to combine numeric with letters you may get complexity so big that your program stops working. Instead of using `secrets.choice` try to check all possible passwords in series. E.g. `aaa`, `aab`, `aac`, etc.

Comment: How can i check all possible passwords? I have to generate first then compare. And secret.choice is seemed a good way to me but if you know more efficient method i would like to hear it because i couldn't see anything else